# viewGroup return null on adapter Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I try adding list with Recyclerview in my fragment. but I getting error in my adapter when adapter try to inflate layout. and I find the viewGroup is null. I have successful last time, but I use Recyclerview in activity not in fragment. I don't know where is my mistake. here my error message.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                                        at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:116)
                                                                        at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:88)
                                                                        at com.unicorn.muf.mockup.feature.tracking.adapter.TrackingAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(TrackingAdapter.kt:21)
                                                                        at com.unicorn.muf.mockup.feature.tracking.adapter.TrackingAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(TrackingAdapter.kt:15)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16952)
```

and here my fragment

```
class TrackingFragment : Fragment(), TrackingAdapter.onItemClick {

private val TAG = "TrackingFragment"
private lateinit var binding : FragmentTrackingBinding
private var list = ArrayList<TrackingModel>()
private var adapter : TrackingAdapter? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_tracking,container,false)
    binding.vRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    binding.vRecyclerview.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    adapter = TrackingAdapter(list,context)
    adapter!!.setOnClick(this)
    binding.vRecyclerview.adapter = adapter

    initdummydata()
    return binding.root
}

override fun onClickItem(model: TrackingModel) {
    val gson = Gson()
    val intent = Intent(context,DetailTrackingActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_GSON, gson.toJson(model))
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun initdummydata(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initData")
    list.add(TrackingModel("WO",5000000,"Karyawan","Parji", "xxxxxasdax", "BA 1234 BA", "Truck", "Asus", "Jakarta", "A4X", "1234", "12334"))
    list.add(TrackingModel("WO",40000,"Karyawan","Parjo", "xxxxxasdax", "BA 1234 BA", "Truck", "Asus", "Jakarta", "A4X", "1234", "12334"))
    list.add(TrackingModel("WO",5000000,"Karyawan","Parje", "xxxxxasdax", "BA 1234 BA", "Truck", "Asus", "Jakarta", "A4X", "1234", "12334"))
    list.add(TrackingModel("WO",1230000,"Karyawan","Parjer", "xxxxxasdax", "BA 1234 BA", "Truck", "Asus", "Jakarta", "A4X", "1234", "12334"))
    list.add(TrackingModel("WO",900000,"Karyawan","Parjip", "xxxxxasdax", "BA 1234 BA", "Truck", "Asus", "Jakarta", "A4X", "1234", "12334"))
    list.add(TrackingModel("WO",1000000000,"Karyawan","Parjan", "xxxxxasdax", "BA 1234 BA", "Truck", "Asus", "Jakarta", "A4X", "1234", "12334"))
    list.add(TrackingModel("WO",5000000,"Karyawan","Parjak", "xxxxxasdax", "BA 1234 BA", "Truck", "Asus", "Jakarta", "A4X", "1234", "12334"))
    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): TrackingFragment = TrackingFragment()
}
```

here my adapter.

```
class TrackingAdapter(var list: MutableList<TrackingModel>, var context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackingAdapter.viewHolder>() {

private var onclick : onItemClick? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
    val binding : ItemTrackingDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context),R.layout.item_tracking_data,parent,false)
    return viewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: viewHolder?, position: Int) {
    val model = list[position]
    holder!!.bind(model)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

inner class viewHolder(private var binding: ItemTrackingDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

    init {
        binding.vLayoutTracking.setOnClickListener({
            val position = adapterPosition
            onclick!!.onClickItem(list[position])
        })
    }

    fun bind(model: TrackingModel){
        binding.vName.text = model.nama
        binding.vNoapp.text = model.no_kontrak
        binding.vNomsn.text = model.no_mesin
        binding.vNopol.text = model.no_polisi
        binding.vStatus.text = model.status
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}

fun setOnClick (onItemClick: onItemClick){
    this.onclick = onItemClick
}

interface onItemClick{
    fun onClickItem(model: TrackingModel)
}
```

I getting error in onCreateviewHolder here.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
    val binding : ItemTrackingDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context),R.layout.item_tracking_data,parent,false)
    return viewHolder(binding)
}
```

I have tracking the parent is null. or is there any my mistake. will very appreciate if any someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace onCreateViewHolder() method with this:

`override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): viewHolder = viewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_tracking_data,parent,false))`

Comment: it's did not work, because inner class in my adapter need databinding return, and with this method will return "view"..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
        val binding : ItemTrackingDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),R.layout.item_tracking_data,parent,false)
        return viewHolder(binding)
    }
```

and let me know if this helped.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i have try that and still not working,. i have tracking its because parent is null.. can you give me suggest, why parent : ViewGrup is null any there is anyway to i fix it ?

Comment: @Frendi please try passing null instead of parent ,parent.getContext()),R.layout.item_tracking_data,null,false)

Answer (score 0):

This very funny, i spend almost all day to resolve this.. my mistake is in my custom xml, i use view like this.

```
<view
    android:background="@color/colorGray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

nothing error but its false view.. the right one is

```
<View
    android:background="@color/colorGray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was migrating to `ViewBinding` from `DataBinding` and I was running the code with `DataBindingUtil.inflate` instead of `ItemBinding.inflate`